# Why are top questions only seen for members with high rep?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, 10k-tools

I have enough rep to access moderation tools on Stack Overflow. One of the great things about it is that I can view the digest of the most notable and interesting questions for a certain time. I check this list everyday! But I can't view it for other Stack Exchange sites, and it is very disappointing. Shouldn't this feature be available for all? Shouldn't great information be shared with everyone?

Comment: Since I do not have this, how does it differ from the sort options given to all users in the "Questions" tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I check this list everyday! But I can't view it for other StackExchange sites, and it is very disappointing.

What you are referring to is at

https://stackexchange.com/

e.g. the top questions across the whole network at any given time.

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I wanted, but there is a mixture of sites, I can't filter by particular ones.

Comment: @andrey yes, you can -- set up a tagset (you can do all questions from a site) http://stackexchange.com/tagsets

Answer (score 1):

Though they do sometimes make for good browsing they are there for the purpose of quality monitoring.

On the other hand, all users do have the [StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838), so that's something.